# Simulate multi-line shell behavior from api

Tags: python, c

In python shell, if i type :

```
def a():
```

And press return, the command will not be evaluated. It will then evaluate the whole block once i finish entering it line by line.

How does the python shell know when it should not process a given input (line)? 
Is it a feature of python (ie python can tell when a line of code is not complete), or a feature of the shell itself (based on regexp, ie when the line ends in a colon, wait for more input) ?

And how can I replicate this behavior using the python C api? If I use the runSimpleString method, it will try to execute any given text so i cant replicate this "wait for more input" feature that the normal python shell does

Comment: You can see the source code for the interactive interpreter in [code.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/code.py) and [codeop.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/codeop.py).

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful! However how do it work? I see that python tries to recompile the code while appending 1 or 2 newlines in case of failure, and catches SyntaxError exceptions but i still dont get it

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't looked at the source code for the Python interpreter, I can tell you how it's likely implemented.

This would not be a function of the terminal (Windows Command Prompt/bash/other), since you're already running the Python interpreter as a program, and terminal emulators vary too much in implementation to rely on them. Further evidence that this is not a function of the terminal is the `>>>` prompt that you see when you run `Python`, not whatever the usual command prompt is `$` or `>`, etc.

Regular Expressions are also not enough to tell whether the end of the code has been reached, because the language (Python) is too complex for RegEx. An [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) would have to be used to determine (near enough, anyway) whether the code is complete.

Therefore, the Python interpreter would have to be a standalone program written in such a way that it uses an AST to parse the given input, then evaluate the program as Python when it has been determined that the code is complete enough to attempt execution.

Comment: thanks! But I'm not sure it can work this way: from what I understood any python shell or IDE like Idle, will just forward calls to the python API for the execution of actual python code. This would mean that the Idle software for instance would require to have a full python syntax parser built-in, for no other purpose than checkin if a given line is a full statement or not?

Comment: You're right, repeating code like that would not be practical. I expect there is some interface built into the Python code to access the parser.